# what is the meaning of the lines in the following code

Tags: java

In the code below I dont understand what the following lines mean

```
a.if (messageProvider == null) and ..
```

Below we are printing the "you must set the ...."

but what  is the point of  "StandardOutMe...getname())"

```
b.{            
                throw new RuntimeException( "You must set the property messageProvider of class:"    +
        StandardOutMessageRenderer.class.getName());       

                }
```

and below is the full program

```
1. public class StandardOutMessageRenderer implements MessageRenderer 
            {   
            private MessageProvider messageProvider; 

            @Override    
            public void render() 
            {        
            if (messageProvider == null) 
            {            
            throw new RuntimeException( "You must set the property messageProvider of class:"    +
    StandardOutMessageRenderer.class.getName());       

            } 

                        System.out.println(messageProvider.getMessage());   
             } 

         @Override    
        public void setMessageProvider(MessageProvider provider)
         {       
         this.messageProvider = provider;   
         } 

        @Override    
        public MessageProvider getMessageProvider()
         {       
         return this.messageProvider;    
        }

        }
```

Comment: It means you must set the message provider

Comment: it will return the name of class which in this case is 'StandardOutMessageRenderer'

Comment: 1. Learn to properly format your code in question.  It took me 10 second to struggle how can `a.if (messageProvider == null) and ..` being a piece of Java code.  2. Get yourself a Java intro book and read and practice thru it.  It is simply too much to teach someone that even don't understand what is `if (something == null)`

Comment: @AdrianShum Thanks for the kind words

Comment: @13thGhost OMG  Thanks, it is simply returning the name of the class. I was thinking like if you have already written "StandardOutMessageRenderer" in SYSO then why bother wirthing StandardOutMessageRenderer.class.getName());

Comment: it is not writing the class name to stdout.  It is simply throwing an exception.  It is the `java` command that decided to write out uncaught exception to stdout/stderr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class offers a method `render()` that does console output of a `messageProvider.getMessage()`.

For that the `messageProvider` must be set.

Comment: public class HelloWorldDecoupled {    public static void main(String[] args) {        MessageRenderer mr = new StandardOutMessageRenderer();        MessageProvider mp = new HelloWorldMessageProvider();        mr.setMessageProvider(mp);        mr.render();    } } ...This is the class with main method. How come we are not using the getMessageProvider() method in this class

Comment: Because they made a field `messageProvider` (that was needed for `render`) together with the `setter`, they also provided a `getter`. Not needed, but now one can always check at any place, which messageProvider is used, or even whether there is a messageProvider. A kind of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you have a class StandardOutMessageRenderer which implements the interface MessageRenderer and provides implementation for render() ,setMessageProvider() and getMessageProivider() .

The class has an instance variable of type MessageProvider and it's value needs to be set by calling the setMessageProvider() method.

render() would first check if the messageProvider has been set or not, if you call render() without setting the value it would throw a RuntimeException displaying the name of the class name else it would print the message to the console and getMessageProvider() is simply a getter for the instance variable.

Comment: Thanks.what i understand is, when we set the value of setMessageProvider() from another  class, the control comes to StandardOutMessageRenderer, and the value is passed to the messageProvider instance variable through setMessageProvider()  method, and the render() method checks if the value is set or not..Iam I right ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. render() just performs a check if it is set or not. if it is not set to null it will print the message else throw an exception.

Comment: thanks for the edit. Earlier I couldn't get it, cause it was mentioned render() and setMessageProvider() do the same thing

Comment: Yeah sorry it was a mistake on my part. I did not read it carefully.